# JavaScript: Parsing date string by string mask

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, date

Let's say I have string arrays with mixed data, e.g.

["Sam", "2019-01", "USA", "2019-03", "Business", "Whatever", "10.000" ... ]

I have to extract just dates ["2019-01", "2019-03" ...]

Is there any universal way to use a regular expression with 0000-00 mask?

The mask could be 0000-00, 0000 (2019), 0000-00-00 (2015-03-25) or even ABC 00 0000 (Mar 25 2015) depending on source data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Or even_? Please, write what the actual case is, without leaving unmentioned possibly relevant details.

Comment: Once again, I have a string array with different data—names, dates, categories and etc. I have to find all the dates in it, by using a filter. Let's say, this array contains dates in "2019-01" format. So what I have to do to get ["2019-01", "2019-03"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if you success to parse it to `Date` object:

```
function isDate(str){
   return !!new Date(str).getTime()
}
```

```js
const tests = [
    '02-20-2020',
    'MAR 03 2017',
    '3 9 op',
    'FEB 05 2000',
    '000-00-00',
    '2019-03'
];

function isDate(str){
   return !!new Date(str).getTime()
}

tests.forEach(t => console.log(isDate(t))); 
// output: true, true, false, true, false, true
```

Comment: Kinda work, but surprisingly awesome for my task. Cheers.

Comment: This is quite unreliable, there are various strings that are recognised as dates by some implementations and not others, and a huge number of valid timestamps that are not recognised as dates by any implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is elegant, but actually I was looking for this:

```
//2019-01 mask
var re = new RegExp(/[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}/g, "i");
var str = "2019-01";

console.log(re.test(str)); //returns true

//Wed, 25 Sep 11
var re = new RegExp(/[A-Za-z]{3}\,\ [0-9]{2}\ [A-Za-z]{3}\ [0-9]{2}/g, "i");
var str = "Wed, 25 Sep 11";
console.log(re.test(str)); //returns true
```

Comment: While I need only one mask at a time and it has to be under control, this solution is much better. Besides, this mask could be anything, not just a date.